# Selection of a file by permissions in linux

Tags: c++, linux, file, permissions, selection

Alright, so I'm doing a function in Linux (with C++) in which I gotta retrieve the files inside a directory with a concrete permission, for example: retrieving all the files in X directory with read permission.

To do this I'm using the stat() function and the st_mode variable. The problem is that I seem to be unable to make the stat function return correctly a stat struct (from which I get the needed st_mode).

The function is the following one (not complete yet):

```
void Search::filePermissionSelection () 
{
    dirStream = opendir (directory.c_str());

    if (dirStream == NULL)
    {
        cout << "error reading directory" << endl;
        exit (0);
    }
    else
    {
        struct stat statResult;
        int error = 0;

        while ((dirDirent = readdir (dirStream)) != NULL)
        {
            error = stat (dirDirent->d_name, &statResult);
            cout << dirDirent->d_name << " -> Value: " << error << endl;

            if (error == 0)
            {
                if (statResult.st_mode & S_IRUSR) cout << "Read permission ";    
                if (statResult.st_mode & S_IWUSR) cout << "Write permission ";    
                if (statResult.st_mode & S_IXUSR) cout << "Exec permission";    
                cout << endl;
            }
        }   
        closedir (dirStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Been a while since I deal with this stuff, but won't `dirDirent->d_name` be **JUST** the filename in the directory? You'd have to include the path as well, e.g. `directory.c_str + dirDirent->d_name`

Comment: That's one thing I thought at first too, but as the manual says (man 2 stat) the stat function just needs the name of the file, which you get from the dirent->d_name. My friends (this is a class project) did it the same way I did, they called stat the same exact way, and it worked for them.
Nevertheless I checked what you said and it doesn't work :P
Thx for your help though :)

Comment: That's fine. but if your app is running as `/home/foo` and you're stat()ing `/home/subdir/filename`, then your code is doing `stat('/home/filename')` and will fail, unless `filename` happens to exist in both locations.

Comment: I also guess that you would want to skip the entries for `.` and `..`

Comment: Well, with the method you told me above it works. I talked with a friend and he told me he is doing it this same way but, the counterpart is that other guy, who got his function done by the professor has stat() called as I called it here, and it works for him. Guess I'll ask him tomorrow ._. Thx for your help :P

Comment: So, what's your output?  If error is not 0, what's errno?

Comment: @MarcB is almost right - you need to add a '/' in between those too, and be careful to do the string concatenation using the C++ std::string type rather than adding char*s together and/or with character constants: (directory + '/' + dirDirent->d_name).c_str()